# How to convert pixel coordinates in 1/72 inches?

Tags: react-native, pdf, react-native-pdf, pdf-lib.js

guys. I am working on documents signature implementation. It have few steps:

User see PDF file and should tap on the place where signature should be placed. On this step I'm using https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf this library to display document and take tap's coordinates.
After step 1 I navigate user to the screen where he should draw his signature.
After user draw signature I'm using pdf-lib drawImage() method to sign document.
There is few problems in this approach:

0, 0 coordinates from react-native-pdf are in top left corner and as I understand coordinates are in pixels.
pdf-lib as I found out is using 1/72 inch as measurements units and 0, 0 point is in bottom left corner.
As result I can sign the document but with wrong placement of signature. So I need some way to properly convert coordinates taken from react-native-pdf to coordinates that are used by pdf-lib to place signature.
I already tried a lot of variants but no one works fine. In current implementation I'm using formula like this:
(pageHeight - signatureCoords.y) / (160 * PixelRatio.get()) / 72
So maybe someone can give me an advice how to properly place signature in PDF?

Comment: The PDF coordinates are indeed in 1/72 inch. The (0,0) point may be the bottom left corner in your particular PDF, but that will not always be the case. You must get the CropBox and MediaBox from the PDF, preferring the CropBox if available. Your PDF library will have functions for this. You will also need to know the current scale the PDF is being displayed at. Once you have all this, the rest is just maths.

Comment: Hi, @johnwhitington. Tell me please how exactly can I use CropBox? As I can see from documentation "The CropBox of a page defines the region to which the contents of the page shall be clipped when displayed or printed." and it returns {x, y, width, height} where x and y are document's lower left corner coords. Don't you know what units are used for cropBox x, y? Pixels or 1/72 inches? And maybe you can help me with conversion of pixels to 1/72 inches?

Comment: Everything PDF related is in 1/72 inches. To do the conversion from pixels to that, you will need to know the scale at which the PDF is currently being rendered, i.e the bounding box of the PDF display in your webpage. If the whole page is not being displayed, you will need the scroll positions too. Before you get into all that, have you checked the function is not available in pdf-lib? The act of picking a position in a displayed document and getting back the position in the source document is a pretty common thing to want to do. Suggest you look through the documentation thoroughly first...